# ExeConfigurationFileMap: InvalidArgumentException, The string parameter 'fileMap.ExeConfigFilename' cannot be null or empty

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, configurationmanager

I am getting an InvalidArgumentException when I run my application.  I am attempting to create a new ExeConfigurationFileMap, and then load it with ConfigurationManager.

```
    public static ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\QuikSnap\\QuikSnap.config");
    public static Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(Settings.configFile, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

I have also attempted to set the configuration file after declaring it, but still didn't have any luck.

If I attempt to continue after this exception, I next receive a TypeInitalizationException upon trying to set a variable to one of the values in the configuration file.

Comment: Could you please add more code that could assist us with debugging your problem. Please also explain in detail what is going wrong.

Comment: @fizzix Not sure what else I can add.  The code breaks within those lines of code upon launch when I try to set a variable to one of the values in the configuration file. 

If I attempt to continue after this exception, I next receive a TypeInitalizationException upon trying to set a variable to one of the values in the configuration file.

All in all, I run my application, and it throws the InvalidArgumentException, telling me that fileMap.ExeConfigFilename cannot be null or empty, even though I *think* I am setting it.

Comment: Michael, that is perfect. I am no C# expert, so if you have provided the correct code and information in your question, I am sure someone will be able to help you out very soon :)

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this same problem. For some ridiculous reason, initializing ExeConfigurationFileMap even with the filepath does not set the property ExeConfigFilename which is required by the Configuration objects constructor. I fixed it by immediately setting that property after instantiating the ExeConfigurationFileMap object like below:

```
public static ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\QuikSnap\\QuikSnap.config");
configFile.ExeConfigFilename = "QuikSnap.config";
public static Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(Settings.configFile, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set the right property with the value of the config file path.
Also, you have a static variable dependency on another static variable in the same class. There could be potentially an issue of order of execution here (though i'm not sure)
Try this instead:

```
public static Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap()
{
    ExeConfigFilename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\QuikSnap\\QuikSnap.config"
}, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```